# How to retrieve the process id of script running in different script

Tags: unix, process, scripting

This is a little complicated case for me.

I want to track if the 'script1_sparkSubmit01.sh' is completed or not which is triggered by Main.sh; if not then wait for it to complete; if completed, then proceed with the remaining script(s) in the main.sh.

**Main Script: Main.sh**

```
ksh script1_sparkSubmit01.sh 2>&1 &
pid=$!
echo $pid
while [ 1 ]
do
    [ -n "$pid" ] && sleep 60 || break
done
ksh script2_sparkSubmit02.sh 2>&1 &
```

**Another script: script1_sparkSubmit01.sh**

```
spark-submit --jars $sqldriver_jar_path  $spark_jar_path/table-load_2.11-1.0.jar  >> ${log_dir}/$log_file_name1 2>&1 &
```

Currently, pid is giving some random value which when I lookup is not available in the current shell. However, I see the 'spark-submit' command of script1_sparkSubmit01.sh running in the current shell.

Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

**Taking the PID from the script which 'script1_sparkSubmit01.sh' triggers  - did work out to me.**

```
ksh script1_sparkSubmit01.sh 2>&1 & 

while [ 1 ]
do
    pid=$(ps -aux | grep 'table-load_2.11-1.0.jar' | grep -v "grep" | awk '{print $2}')
    [ -n "$pid" ] && sleep 30 || break
done
ksh script2_sparkSubmit01.sh 2>&1 &
```